# jQuery responsive Datatables Customize CSS and Pagination

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, datatables

I am using `jQuery` and `jQuery datatables` (1.10.1) to create a "responsive" datatables. I am trying to customize 2 things 
1. Look and feel by giving my own `CSS`
2. Pagination and search controls.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/urwyrj89/

I have added my own `CSS` but it does not seem to take it because my `CSS` has `background-color` which does not show up on UI :

```
.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #d6e9f8;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #333;
}
```

But it never applies it. I tried putting the `class` directly as well as substituting at run time in `jQuery`. I am new to this, so will appreciate some pointers ?

Also, I want to customize the pagination control. Instead of default view i.e.

[image]

I want the control to be like below and also, the positioned to both on top and bottom

[image]

Is that customization possible? Any pointers on how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply your style using the rule below or use `!important` which is less preferable.

```css
table.dataTable.tablesorter thead th, 
table.dataTable.tablesorter tfoot th {
    background-color: #d6e9f8;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #333;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urwyrj89/1/) for demonstration.

---

Regarding pagination, there is [Select list](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/select) pagination plug-in. You need to include appropriate plug-in JS and use `pagingType: "listbox"` initialization option, see the example below:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    pagingType: "listbox"
} );
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urwyrj89/2/) for demonstration.